# Bulk Collect Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Can bulk collect be done if data is getting inserted into table A from Table B and while selecting data, substr, instr, trunc functions has been used on columns fetched?

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT
DISTINCT 
    SUBSTR(b.component, 1, INSTR(b.component, ':', 1)  - 1),
    TRUNC(c.end_dt, 'DDD'),
FROM 
    B b,
    C c
WHERE 
    TRUNC(c.end_dt)=TRUNC(b.last_Date, 'DDD') ;
```

How can I insert data into table A using bulk collect?

Comment: Bulk collect is meant to improve the performance of procedural row-by-row processing.  But you've already got a SQL solution, which is almost always the best way to do it.

Comment: don't use bulk collect in this case, you're doing the best you can already (staying within the sql engine is the best to do). Also, don't trunc dates as much you can unless you're sure you have proper function indices.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you'd use Bulk Collect and FORALL to insert rows is when you absolutely need to process/insert rows in chunks. Otherwise always use SQL.

```
DECLARE 
   CURSOR c_data IS
   SELECT * FROM source_tab;
--
  TYPE t_source_tab IS TABLE OF source_tab%ROWTYPE;
  l_tab t_source_tab;
  v_limit  NUMBER:= 1000;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_data;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_data BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab LIMIT v_limit; 
    EXIT WHEN l_tab.count = 0;
    -- Insert --    
    FORALL i IN l_tab.first .. l_tab.last
      INSERT INTO destination_tab VALUES l_tab(i);
      COMMIT;

      -- prints number of rows processed --
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Inserted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows:'); 

    -- Print nested table of records - optional. 
    -- May overflow the buffer and slow down the performance if you process many rows.
    -- Use for testing only and limit the rows with Rownum or Row_Number() in cursor query:
    FOR i IN l_tab.FIRST..l_tab.LAST -- or l_tab.COUNT
    LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_tab(i).hire_date ||chr(9)||l_tab(i).last_name ||chr(9)||l_tab(i).first_name);
    END LOOP;    

 END LOOP;
CLOSE c_data;
END
/
```